# Does phonegap support Android 1.6?

Tags: android, cordova

I am following [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) guide and based on [here](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/30862722/phonegap-android-eclipse-quickstart), it says

> Don't bother using older versions of Android. Use the highest SDK
>   target available. Phonegap will take care of backwards compatibility
>   for you.

So I use these targets:

Build target

> Android 2.3.3

and

> minimum SDK 4

and use

> cordova-1.9.0.jar

but gives following error when I try to run it on Android 1.6

```
E/dalvikvm(200): Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.<init>, referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.<init>
W/dalvikvm(200): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 285: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;IZ)V
W/dalvikvm(200): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x70 at 0x0001
W/dalvikvm(200): VFY:  rejected Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;IZ)V
W/dalvikvm(200): Verifier rejected class Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView;
D/AndroidRuntime(200): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(200): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
E/AndroidRuntime(200): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(200): java.lang.VerifyError: org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView
E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.init(DroidGap.java:297)
E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.loadUrl(DroidGap.java:343)
E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at phone.gap.test.PhonegapTestActivity.onCreate(PhonegapTestActivity.java:13)
E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
E/AndroidRuntime(200):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

However it runs well when I run it on Android 2.3.3.
Does Phonegap not support Android 1.6?

Comment: what url you have loaded in droidgap.loadurl()?

Comment: I am loading file:///android_asses/www/index.html and there is the html file inside assets -> www folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap 1.0 removed support for Android releases before 2.1. You could use one of the [0.9.x releases](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/tags) with Android 1.6.

Comment: is it possible to have 2 releases jar and js on a project?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PhoneGap 1.9, have a look at this: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20Android

While it would be ideal to support back to 1.6, you're only giving up <1% of your potential market reach if you move up to 2.1.  Previous answers on this topic have also suggested using 2.1 (minSdkLevel="7") as your bottom end.

Comment: seems no luck..which topic? I understand I only have very small market for 1.6 version but I still need to make it for Android 1.6 :(

Comment: Sorry, not much more I can offer.  I do not use PhoneGap myself.

Comment: I have same issue some one can help me :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839836/salesforce-android-app-remote-access-application-authorization